# Unity Движение объекта в произвольную сторону

Tags: c#, unity3d

Имеется часть кода для движения персонажа.
Работало так - вращаем камеру, туда же вращается персонаж и двигаем его по

```
Vector3.forward
```

Код всёго этого дела

```
_motionData = new Vector3(MotionStickDirection.x, 0, MotionStickDirection.y); //Получаем данные от джойстика

_angle = GetAngleAroundAxis(Vector3.forward, _motionData, Vector3.up); // Проекция вектора на ось

_newRotation = Quaternion.Euler(transform.eulerAngles.x, _angle + CameraEulerAngles.y, transform.eulerAngles.z); // Вычисляем, на сколько надо повернуть объект, чтобы он смотрел туда же, куда и камера

transform.rotation = _newRotation; // Вращаем нас в ту же сторону

var newPos = transform.position + transform.forward; // Назначаем позицию для движения. Чуть чуть вперёд. 

transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, newPos, Time.fixedDeltaTime * _speed); // Двигаемся туда

float GetAngleAroundAxis(Vector3 firstVector, Vector3 secondVector, Vector3 axis)
{
            var v1 = firstVector - Vector3.Project(firstVector, axis);
            var v2 = secondVector - Vector3.Project(secondVector, axis);
            var angle = Vector3.Angle(v1, v2);
            return angle * (Vector3.Dot(axis, Vector3.Cross(v1, v2)) < 0 ? -1 : 1);
 }
```

А как сделать так, чтобы он мог двигаться в произвольном направлении, используя эти же даннные? Не в два этапа, допустим, поворот->движения прямо, а без поворота, просто двигаться в ту сторону?

Добавлено позже.
Можно просто делать так

```
var newPos = transform.position + new Vector3(сontroller.MotionStickDirection.y, 0, сontroller.MotionStickDirection.x).normalized; 


transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, newPos, Time.fixedDeltaTime * _speed);
```

Но тогда движение будет абсолютным, т.е. как бы не был повёрнут персонаж - его всё равно будет тащить на север\юг\запад\восток. А нужно относительное движение, как с

```
transform.forward\backward\left\right
```

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не уверен, что это решение абсолютно, но оно работает. Буду рад, если есть более красивые варианты.

```
var dirY = transform.forward * сontroller.MotionStickDirection.y;
var dirX = transform.right * сontroller.MotionStickDirection.x;

newPos = transform.position + dirX + dirY;

transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, newPos, Time.fixedDeltaTime * _speed);
```

Объект движется в нужную сторону относительно своих осей.